# Possible to Dynamically Connect to Postgres DB from Laravel without using Config ? See Example

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a situation where I'd like to dynamically choose the DB host for postgres DB connections in a Laravel application running in Docker.  I don't particularly want to use ENV values or the config/database.php file because it is a one-off query to the external DB that I would prefer to embed in Helper Class.

These actually could go in the .env file:

```
PSQL_DB_PORT=5432
PSQL_DB_DATABASE=postgres
PSQL_DB_USERNAME=postgres
PSQL_DB_PASSWORD=postgres
```

and in my helper I can get the **hostname** for the remote (actually in Docker) postgres server, which will basically be something like:

postgres_index-db1, postgres_index-db2, postgres_index-db3, etc., but I need to fetch that dynamically and store it in a variable **$host**.

I tried playing around with a thing like this:

```
    DB::disconnect('pgsql');
    Config::set("database.connections.pgsql", [
    
                'driver' => 'pgsql',
                'host' => $host ,
                'port' => env('PSQL_DB_PORT', '5432'),
                'database' => env('PSQL_DB_DATABASE'),
                'username' => env('PSQL_DB_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('PSQL_DB_PASSWORD'),
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'prefix' => '',
                'prefix_indexes' => true,
                'schema' => 'public',
                'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ]);
    dd(DB::connection('pgsql'));
    $query = "select DISTINCT value from maindicomtags where taggroup = 8 and tagelement = 128";
    $names = DB::connection('pgsql')->select($query,[]);
```

and the **dd(DB::connection('psql'))** (a Laravel dump) statement actually shows the correct config, but when the query tries to execute it must be looking for the pgsql config in my config/database.php file because it throws an error:

```
Database connection [pgsql] not configured
```

because it must be looking for the config in the config/database.php file, and I removed the definition from there.  I want it to use the connection that is defined above.

Is there a a way to do what I am trying to do.  I could even just use the connection string for Postgres if that is possible.

**Might actually be working because I might have had a typo earlier (e.g. psql vsl pgsql).**

Does this seem like an adequate way to make that type of dynamic connection ?  It is really just the host that will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting your config, just create a custom database connection using factory. The only downside - you will not be able to use Eloquent as it resolves connection by its name defined in configs. Also, avoid using env variables anywhere else than config files - create other config and use it instead. There is quite a chance something could break somewhere else if you change config on the go:

```php
$factory = app(\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::class);

$db = $factory->make([
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => $host ,
    'port' => $port ?? 5432,
    'database' => $database,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
]);

$names = $db->table('maindicomtags')
    ->where('taggroup', 8)
    ->where('tagelement', 128)
    ->distinct()
    ->pluck('value');

$db->disconnect();
```

Comment: I'll give that a try.  That is pretty much when I am looking for.  Do I need to destroy or close the connection when done or will that just happen automatically ?  I basically want to create it, do what I need, and then throw it away.

Comment: BTW, I see you work with Laravel and Vue.  Is there a way to get in touch with you outside of SO ?

Comment: Yea, as long as your connection is not persistent, would be better to disconnect from the database when you are done. Sorry, but I'm not really into personal consulting and would prefer to help people when I'm in the mood to help.

Comment: Perfect.  Just what I needed.  See you around then.  I actually spent about 4 months in Ukraine back in 2017-18.

Comment: One last question regarding that.  I would prefer that that connection be 'read-only'.  It might be moot because I am just executing SELECT statements using that connection, but I think I might be encountering some DB locks, serialization errors with retries sometimes when I access that DB.  It looks like there might be a way to do that in Laravel such that a write simply won't execute, but seems to work fine so far.